# how to get the purchase order items in advanced pdf check template in Netsuite

Tags: netsuite

I am having a check template where I can print the Vendor payment information. Now I want to get the Purchase Order information like PO number, PO Date and some custom fields. I can able to drill down from Payments to "apply" bill. Further I could not drill down to PO level. Do anyone have idea on how to proceed on this.

I am getting the BILL information using the below code

```
<#if check.apply?has_content>
<#list check.apply as bill>
  <tr>
    <td>${bill.applydate}</td>
    <td>${bill.refnum}</td>
    <td align="right">${bill.amount}</td>
  </tr>
  </#list>
</#if>
```

Comment: Is the PO number/date specifically listed on the check template in Netsuite?
I usually access information via ${record.custbodyXX} or ${record.entity.phone}, etc

Comment: No, its not listed in the check template. Is there a way to get it from the check variable?

Comment: You won't be able to access anything from the check template unless it's already existing somewhere in the record itself. If the PO is linked to the check via related records or something like "Created From" you should be able to access it via `${record.PO.ponumber}` (psuedocode, depending on your field values}

Comment: Did you succeed in doing so?

Comment: The "Created From" field is not available in the form. So, I have created fields in the Vendor Payment page and get the value from the corresponding PO (using suitescript). From there, I picked up the values to the check template